# Spring dynamics, two balls

Tags: c++, game-physics

I'm trying to wrap my head around physics, so I'm writing a 2D physics simulation.

My current problem is getting two balls to correctly bounce off each other using spring dynamics.

`obj->v` contains velocity, `obj->spring` contains the spring properties of the current object, `spring.comp` is the current compression,
`angle` is the angle between the two objects.

Collision check is working correctly.

I've been trying different things, blindly, and this is obviously wrong:

```c
obj->v.x = (-obj->spring.stiffness*obj->spring.comp) - sin(angle)*(obj->v.x)
obj->v.y = (-obj->spring.stiffness*obj->spring.comp) - cos(angle)*(obj->v.y)
```

In addition, I want to take into account both the velocity and weight of both objects.

Comment: Are we talking the kind of balls we find on a billiard table and the kind of collisions they experience there? Then I think I would not use springs at all. Are you aware of the laws of preservation? Energy preservation and momentum preservation. (Sorry, not sure about the words "preservation" (not changing) and "momentum " (mass times speed) here).

Comment: @Yunnosch impulse -> momentum

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Thanks.

Comment: I think you are looking for elastic and non elastic collision of objects, and you can find the equation to calculate the conservation of momentum and the equation with little research

Comment: @Yunnosch the transfer of energy is the same as between billiard balls i suppose, except the transfer of energy takes place over a certain time (stiffness of spring*compression of spring) instead of instantly.

Comment: Yes, but the end result can much more easily calculated from the preservatin laws than by simulating springs over that short time. That is the beauty of it,